# Excel VBA Generating report based on grouping

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA that I created. It generates an output based on an input file.

In that file, there is a field that contains usernames, these usernames are repeated throughout the column.

What I need to do is, assign the usernames to separate cells to be unique not repeated, and then count the repeated ones.

Comment: could you explain in detail how your input file is and how you want exactly your output? In the input file you have usernames in newlines? and those usernames are repeated? Are in the same line? Are comma separated? and you want that in the excel a username for each cell (in a single column) but without repeat them?

Comment: each in a single cell. But in the same row

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have my excel worksheet setup as follows:

1. List of usernames in column A
2. In column B I want all unique usernames
3. In column C I want a count of how many of each name there are

   ```
       Username     Unique     Count
   1   John         John       1
   2   Susan        Susan      2
   3   Chris        Chris      3
   4   Susan
   5   Chris
   6   Chris
   ```

I can do this in VBA by putting the usernames into a dictionary where the `Key` is the username and the `Value` is the number of repetitions. I then just iterate over the dictionary to get the desired output.

This code worked for me:

```
Sub UserNameCount()
    Dim usernames As Range, name As Range, rw As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set usernames = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    rw = 2

    For Each user In usernames
        If Not dict.Exists(user.Value) Then
            dict.Add user.Value, 1
        Else
            dict.Item(user.Value) = dict.Item(user.Value) + 1
        End If
    Next user

    For Each v In dict.Keys
        Range("B" & rw) = v
        Range("C" & rw) = dict.Item(v)
        rw = rw + 1
    Next

    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

*NB: you may need to do Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime to get the dictionary to work*